# Tired of Talking to Robots

Tags: feature-request, captcha, required-tags

I meet the robot page pretty regularly, and it's always the same process.

1. Set up a question here
2. Forget to add one of the required tags
3. get dinged
4. add the tag
5. submit

*danger, danger Will Robinson*

Would the team consider a special case for this situation? That is, if I just got the bird for a lack of tags, I should be allowed to post again with no minimum time.

Comment: It's not a solution per se, but CAPTCHA rates are *drastically* reduced once you hit 10k, for all reasons. Since hitting 10k, I haven't even seen one at all yet I do some pretty rapid edits. Telling someone to "go get rep" isn't much of a good solution, but at the same time I'm not sure I feel that there needs to be a particularly special case here.

Comment: It does it when you edit an answer/question twice in a row as well.  10k seems quite high, haven't we proved we are probably OK after 5k?

Comment: (It [has been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47047/please-give-me-a-choice-not-to-use-googles-recaptcha-and-help-them-stealing-books/47074#47074) that it's good enough to only type the word that is most easily read.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please remove captcha for editing and tagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73650/please-remove-captcha-for-editing-and-tagging)

Comment: Is robo editing really so rampant that we need the robots?  Seems weird, but it is. Could posts getting rapid edits just show up in the 10k tools for people to keep an eye on them?

Comment: You could clarify the feature request, so it doesn't appear as duplicate. My literal reading is that you are not annoyed by the CAPTCHA itself, but by the same old same old robots? If so, the proposed solution would be to have rotating and **much more entertaining comic strips** in place of the the robots. Right?

Comment: If you're seeing this, it may actually be a bug! (or you just resubmitted too fast) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72542/no-need-to-verify-us-as-a-human-being-twice-or-more/73762#73762